# Inner product of a multivector and kth-exterior of the dual space?

Tags: operator-algebras, projective-geometry, exterior-algebra, dual-spaces

I'm working through a proof of the Grassmannian as a subvariety and came across this:

Let V be an n-dimensional vector space, and let $\Lambda$ $\in$ $\wedge$$^k$V be a decomposable multivector of the form $\Lambda$ = v$_1$ $\wedge$ v$_2$ $\wedge$ $\dots$ $\wedge$ v$_k$.

i(v$^*$): $\wedge$$^k$V $\rightarrow$ $\wedge$$^{k-1}$V is a contraction operator defined for v$^*$$\in$ V$^*$ by

$\langle$i(v$^*)$$\Lambda$, $\Xi$$\rangle$ = $\langle$$\Lambda$, v$^*$$\wedge$ $\Xi$$\rangle$
for all $\Xi$ $\in$ ($\wedge$$^{k-1}$V)$^*$$\cong$ $\wedge$$^{k-1}$V$^*$

I'm assuming this last bit is defining the contraction as some sort of inner product, but I have no intuition on how this inner product (of a multivector with a kth-exterior product of the dual space) might work. Can anyone help me out, or at least point me towards something helpful?

Comment: There's basically only one choice of inner product (up to an overall constant, perhaps) that's consistent with all of the ingredients: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Inner_product

Comment: Thank you! Quick question though: so now I have this characterization i$_{v^*}$(w)(u$_1$, u$_2$, ..., u$_{k-1}$) = w(v$^*$, u$_1$, u$_2$, ..., u$_{k-1}$). But what happens when you multiply (concatenate?) the multivector w by this cartesian product? Do one of the elements of the cartesian product divide out some v$_i$ from w = v$_1$ $\wedge$ v$_2$ $\wedge$ ... $\wedge$ v$_k$ to make it an element of $\wedge$$^{k-1}$V?

Comment: The first equation you write is actually the definition of the contraction operator $i_{v^*}$. I don't see which "Cartesian product" your question asks about.

Comment: From the article's section on the interior product (a little above the inner product section): 
"Suppose that w ∈ Λ$^k$V. Then w is a multilinear mapping of V$^∗$ to K, so it is defined by its values on the k-fold Cartesian product V$^∗$ × V$^∗$ × ... × V$^∗$. If u$_1$, u$_2$, ..., u$_{k−1}$ are k − 1 elements of V$^∗$, then define..." the characterization above. The Cartesian product in question is the string (u$_i$) of k-1 values in V$^*$.